# How to maintain the size of delimiter space with respect to (+/-) digits?

Tags: python, string, templates, string-formatting

I need to make small template with 8 columns that will be separated by white space as follows:

Expected output:

```
3139  3142  3144  3147     1      169.13   0  2000
3144  3147  3165  3167     1      049.2    0  2000
3142  3144  3147  3149     1      065.02   0  2000
3142  3144  3147  3165     1     -168.52   0  2000
3144  3147  3149  3150     1     -172.09   0  2000 
3144  3147  3165  3161     1      171.15   0  2000
```

but I am getting unequal white space because of negative value presence in 6th column as follows:

Actual output:

```
3139  3142  3144  3147     1      169.13   0  2000
3144  3147  3165  3167     1      049.20   0  2000
3142  3144  3147  3149     1      065.02   0  2000
3142  3144  3147  3165     1      -168.52   0  2000
3144  3147  3149  3150     1      -172.09   0  2000
3144  3147  3165  3161     1      171.15   0  2000
```

So my aim is to trim the white space according +/- value digits in 6th column as I mentioned in the expected output.

Here is my code:

```
from string import Template
import sys

fw=open("sample.txt","w")

DIHRES = ['3139;3142;3144;3147;169.13', '3144;3147;3165;3167;49.20', '3142;3144;3147;3149;65.02',
    '3142;3144;3147;3165;-168.52', '3144;3147;3149;3150;-172.09', '3144;3147;3165;3161;171.15']

for i in DIHRES:
A1 = (i.split(";")[0]).strip()
A2 = (i.split(";")[1]).strip()
A3 = (i.split(";")[2]).strip()
A4 = (i.split(";")[3]).strip()
ANG = (i.split(";")[4]).strip()
str = '''
$A1  $A2  $A3  $A4     1      $ANG   0  2000
        '''
s = Template(str.strip() + "\n")
fw.write(s.substitute(A1=A1, A2=A2, A3=A3, A4=A4, ANG=ANG.rjust(6, '0')))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem strings are 7 characters long.  You are telling ``rjust()`` to use a field with of 6 characters; it will not do anything to strings that are already too long, you need to give it a bigger field width.  Note that padding with '0' is probably not what you want to do here: if the value was ``'-1.00'``, would you really want to pad that to ``'0-1.00'``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more simple solution is to use `format`.  Convert the last item to a float and use a floating point format (7 width, 2 places after decimal).  The 0 indicates leading zeros and the space after the colon indicates place a space for positive numbers and `-` for negative numbers:

```
DIHRES = ['3139;3142;3144;3147;169.13',
          '3144;3147;3165;3167;49.20',
          '3142;3144;3147;3149;65.02',
          '3142;3144;3147;3165;-168.52',
          '3144;3147;3149;3150;-172.09',
          '3144;3147;3165;3161;171.15']

for item in DIHRES:
    data = item.split(';')
    data[-1] = float(data[-1])
    print('{}  {}  {}  {}     1      {: 07.2f}   0  2000'.format(*data))
```

> ```
> 3139  3142  3144  3147     1       169.13   0  2000
> 3144  3147  3165  3167     1       049.20   0  2000
> 3142  3144  3147  3149     1       065.02   0  2000
> 3142  3144  3147  3165     1      -168.52   0  2000
> 3144  3147  3149  3150     1      -172.09   0  2000
> 3144  3147  3165  3161     1       171.15   0  2000
> ```

Comment: Thank you somuch @Mark Tolonen its really helpful

Answer (score 1):

your longest string in ANG was 7 char

```
-172.09
```

and you attempted to justify with only 6

```
.rjust(6, '0')
```

just change this line:

```
fw.write(s.substitute(A1=A1, A2=A2, A3=A3, A4=A4, ANG=ANG.rjust(6, '0')))
```

to:

```
fw.write(s.substitute(
    A1=A1.rjust(6), A2=A2.rjust(6), A3=A3.rjust(6), 
    A4=A4.rjust(6), ANG=ANG.rjust(8)))

>>>
  3139    3142    3144    3147     1        169.13   0  2000
  3144    3147    3165    3167     1         49.20   0  2000
  3142    3144    3147    3149     1         65.02   0  2000
  3142    3144    3147    3165     1       -168.52   0  2000
  3144    3147    3149    3150     1       -172.09   0  2000
  3144    3147    3165    3161     1        171.15   0  2000
```

when setting up columns I like to explicitly justify each; so all are .rjust(6) except for the column where I need more and used .rjust(8)

also, I think you just want rjust with spaces not zeros; so I eliminated that part of your code.

a step further, if your input had data like this:

```
'3144;3147;3165;3167;49.2'
```

or even

```
'3144;3147;3165;3167;49'
```

instead of:

```
'3144;3147;3165;3167;49.20'
```

this could be resolved by first string formatting the column to contain 2 decimal places:

```
fw.write(s.substitute(A1=A1.rjust(6), A2=A2.rjust(6), 
    A3=A3.rjust(6), A4=A4.rjust(6), 
    ANG=('%.2f' % float(ANG)).rjust(8)))
```

in this way you would keep your decimal points aligned regardless of input on that column, which is what I think you really want; more so than the "expected solution":

```
049.2
```

the .format solution by Mark Tolonen also resolves the 2 position decimal float issue

Comment: Thank you somuch @Litepresence its really helpful